# snprintf to concatenate multiple strings don't work as expected

Tags: c, string, printf

It has been pointed out in quite a few places that to concatenate multiple strings it is more easy and also elegant to use snprintf instead of running multiple runs of strcat. But I've been getting incorrect results because of that. In this little snippet below which is part of program to convert 12hr to 24hr time, I first separate the hr,min and sec part and after converting the time, re-join the strings again.

here's the snippet

```
/*  
char *timestr = strcat(hr, min);
timestr = strcat(timestr, sec);
timestr = strcat(timestr, AMPM);
*/

///*    
char *timestr = (char *)malloc(20);
snprintf(timestr, sizeof(timestr), "%s:%s:%s", hr,min,sec);
//*/
```

the first version works fine but the bottom one doesn't. Here's the expected output which is what I see with strcat

```
(gdb) p timestr
$1 = 0x7fffffffe8cd "190545PM"
```

this is what I see with snprintf

```
(gdb) p timestr
$1 = 0x801007040 "19:05:4"
```

I am unable to fathom what is going wrong. Isn't printing to the stream supposed to take care of the trailing NULL character?

Comment: Check the return value of `snprintf`. if `n >= size` then truncation occurred. Truncation includes failing to add the trailing `NULL`. And if `n == -1` then an error occurred. Android used to return `-1` when it should have succeeded due to lack of language support. For your example (and if on a desktop), you should get the truncation condition.

Comment: @jww `snprintf` always null-terminates

Answer (score 2):

In case of `snprintf` if the second argument is `n` then manual says

> If the resulting string would be longer than n-1 characters, the remaining characters are discarded and not stored, but counted for the value returned by the function.

So what is the case here for `n`? `sizeof(temp)` is `sizeof(char*)` which is not the same as 20 bytes you allocated. You can't apply `sizeof` to a pointer to get the memory size it points to. (On a typical system `sizeof(char*)` varies).

Solution:

```
snprintf(timestr, 20, "%s:%s:%s", hr,min,sec);
```

or if you keep it in some variable (which is recommended).

```
const int size = 20;
int ret = snprintf(timestr, size, "%s:%s:%s", hr,min,sec);
if( ret < 0){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in snprintf operation\n");
    exit(1);
}
if( ret >= size){
   fprintf(stderr,"Error: more characters than expected\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Check the return value of `snprintf` to understand whether same error occured in that case negative number is returned.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value from `snprintf`. All the more reason to use `snprintf_s`. It is easier to use safely, and harder to use incorrectly.

Comment: if `ret >= size` then the result was truncated and the trailing `NULL` was not added.

Comment: @jww.: `snprintf_s` is safer than `snprintf` - Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @jww.: Two things -1) So I can use `snprintf_s` the same way and benefit will be error checking will be same with added bonus now the `\0` is appened at the end in case of overflow? 2) Can you post any manual from where details can be known(usage perspective)?

Comment: @jww you should write your own answer instead of complaining about all the other answers not conforming to your preferred style

Comment: @M.M.: Or maybe by doing this we are learning? jww is correcting and it's interesting to know things like this the hard way. Please don't mind my comment..what you said is right but still..I don't mind being corrected.

Comment: @coderredoc He's wrong in my opinion ... comments to answers are for clarification of the answer, not for general discussion

Comment: @M.M. - the comment is for the benefit of the person answering and the folks who read the answer later.

Comment: @jww "if ret >= size then the result was truncated and the trailing NULL was not added." is incorrect. "... output characters beyond the n-1st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array." is the specified behavior.  A null character is expected.

Comment: @M.M.: Ah it is true these `_s` functions not all safe but it still provides a level of abtraction or some way less bad than the original ones? Is it not so? I am just curious.

Comment: @chux.: Hi chux...ah yes I mentioned it as quote and forgot? facepalm.

Comment: @coderredoc No, `_s` functions are not safer. The key to safe coding involves a numbers of steps, not just using the "right" function.

Comment: @chux.: You mean they are not safer than the original ones? Then why did it come into picture? and C11 mentioned it also. Weird then.

Comment: @coderredoc " Then why did it come into picture?" --> `_s` function smell of   [Embrace, extend, and extinguish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish).  Ever consider why only the most recent MS version of C nearly approaches C99, after **19 years**?

Comment: @chux - [Vulnerability Note VU#922681](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/922681), *a.k.a.* *Multiple Buffer Overflows in libupnp* (and countless other examples) would beg to differ with you. The safer function would not have allowed the overruns by design. How is that not safer than allowing the buffer overflow to occur? Perhaps I am missing something obvious. Please forgive my ignorance if I am.

Comment: @jww.: Correct me if I am wrong - `snprintf` always null terminate the string - the standard says so. Now it might be the case that it is not the complete input that is printed in the buffer - we can understand it by using the return value - if it's `>=size` then we know somehting is truncated. But still the buffer content is `\0` terminated. Isn't this good enough to overcome `snprintf_s`'s features?

Comment: @jww The [link](https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/922681) does not direct any discussion concerning `_s` functions vs. their base implementations and so is not strongly relevant to the issue.  "How is that not safer than allowing the buffer overflow to occur?" is a [straw man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man).  Such discussion is beyond comments and deserves a post on a relevant site.

Comment: @chux.: Would you please check my last comment ..I mean that's how `snprintf` works I suppose if I didn't understand it too wrong?

Comment: @coderredoc Consider `snprintf(command, 18, "Fire the missiles%s", go ? "" : " not");`. A truncated `command` is not so great.  As mentioned, safe coding involves [various steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728522/snprint-to-concatenate-multiple-strings-dont-work-as-expected#comment84456323_48728545)

Comment: @coderredoc Not allowing overruns is one step, various ways to do it.  Simply using `sprintf()`, `snprintf()`, `snprintf_s()` or `sprintf_s()` is not the solution.  More is involved.

Comment: @chux - I happened to study those uPNP  vulnerabilities. I use them as a case study in my secure coding class. `libupnpg` was using all unsafe functions. It is directly relevant to comments. There are no straw men, and you are welcomed to look up the CVEs (they are public). I said *"[they are] is easier to use safely"*. They would have stopped the overflow by design. You said *"No, _s functions are not safer"*. How is allowing the buffer overflow to occur safer?

Comment: @chux.: But yes that's the handling part - that's why in my case the program is exited when that case occurs. Is it not enough? (I am just trying to imrpve the answer)

Comment: @jww It remains a _straw man_ ("while actually refuting an argument that was not presented by that opponent") because you have selected the opposition argument as "allowing the buffer overflow to occur safer", something that I have not espoused.

Comment: @chux.: Is it possible to elaborate a bit if you have time? Is there any space in my answer that I can overcome?

Comment: @chux - The safer functions are designed to stop buffer overflows and designed to be easier to use through consistency. Please explain how allowing the buffer overflow to occur is somehow safer. If you claim they are not safer, then you are stating they are not hitting their design goals. I.e., they are allowing buffer overflows or they are not consistent in their usage. I'd be delighted to hear your reasoning without leading to the contradiction.

Comment: @coderredoc The "handling part" is part of the answer and is why `function()` vs. `function_s()` discussion is insufficient.   Robust code needs to handle the problem well and on only switching between using `function()` vs. `function_s()`  is incomplete.  Checking the return value of `snprintf` is a good step as this answer provides.

Comment: @chux.: Ah that's why I checked the return value...I guess there is anything I am missing? (I mean handling part checks all the cases of error in `snprint`)..Sorry if I didn't get and repeating a question.

Comment: @jww You keep bringing up "how allowing the buffer overflow to occur is somehow safer", something that I have not promoted and ask my to justify it - thus my assertion that it is a _straw man_.  .  It is as is using `sprintf()`  automatically generates a buffer overflow.  It does not.  It depends on the format and the arguments passed to it.

Comment: @chux - Another misdirection. I said *"[they are] easier to use safely"*. They would have stopped the overflow by design. You said *"No, _s functions are not safer"*. How are they not safer, and how would they have not stopped the buffer overflows? The opposite of not stopping it is allowing it to happen. I would be delighted to hear it.

Comment: @coderredoc Given OP's limited problem scope, your use of `snprintf()` is fine.

Comment: @jww `sprintf_s()` 1) lacks compiler implementations as it is not required in the standard C library - thus not well portable.  2) When implemented, as by MS. it uses a different concept of size than the C spec. 3) The design of the function has led to problems with size not being applied to `"%c"` (many SO posts on that).  4) various solutions exist without using  `sprintf_s()`. 
 The pros and cons of `sprintf_s()` deserve a post - more than just this comment.

Comment: @jww "The opposite of not stopping it is allowing it to happen. " is not the only alternative.  Other alternatives exist including how to use `sprintf()` with different format and code.

Comment: @chux - we are talking about the safer string function (`*_s`), which you claim are not safer.

Comment: @jww Similar issues apply to `strcpy_s()`. et al.  This answer is about `sprintf()` and friends and so my discussion focuses on that.  To be clear, "`_s` functions are not safer". does not mean the the non-`_s` are safe or safer or not safe.  Safe coding involves more that just using the right function, but is a result of the set of code used.  As it a bit late, perhaps you would like a final comment?  Good to have read your thoughts.

Comment: @chux - How about: [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures | glibc](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=glibc). glibc makes regular appearances on Bugtraq. Even the experts get it wrong regularly. That's why I push for the safer (*not* completely safe) functions.

Comment: @chux.: Can you give me a link to a post tomorrow (as you said it is late in your place) about the `2)3)` in your comment (`size`  and `%c` etc).

Comment: wow this seems to have evolved into a flame thread of some sort. Nevertheless I am quite satisfied with this as well as the previous answer. Also `snprintf_s` seems to be from the win32 toolkit and I can't  find it natively available on my Linux distro

Comment: @HighOnMeat.: Yes right you are. There might be implementation which didt have them. it's a microsoft thing

Comment: @coderredoc #2 and #3 of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728522/snprintf-to-concatenate-multiple-strings-dont-work-as-expected/48728545#comment84456855_48728545) refer to `scanf()` vs. `scanf_s()`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(timestr)` doesn't return you the number of bytes that you've allocated,
it returns you the number of bytes that a pointer to `char` needs to be stored
in memory. The correct call would be:

```
char *timestr = malloc(20);
snprintf(timestr, 20, "%s:%s:%s", hr,min,sec);
```

Note that `snprintf` will try to write at nost 20 characters (including the
0-terminating byte). If the resulting length is not large enough, `timestr` will
be cropped. So it's better to get the number of bytes that you would need by
passing `NULL` and size 0 to `snprintf`. In this case it will return how many
character would be required. So

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s:%s:%s", hr, min, sec);
if(len < 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "could not execute snprintf\n");
    return; // or whatever, do not continue
}
char *timestr = malloc(len + 1);
if(timestr == NULL)
{
    // error handling
    return; // or whatever, do not continue
}

sprintf(timestr, "%s:%S:%s", hr, min, sec);
```

would give you the exact amount of bytes for the string.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value from `snprintf`. All the more reason to use `snprintf_s`. It is easier to use safely, and harder to use incorrectly.

Comment: @jww where am I ignoring the return value of `snprintf`?

Comment: @jww `snprintf_s` is optional (and not widely supported) and many would disagree with your assessment that it's "easier to use safely".   Failure return codes from `snprintf` basically never happen

Comment: @M.M. - Not to sound too argumentative, but: *many would disagree with your assessment that it's "easier to use safely"*. This question and answers  (and all the other real life  failures and associated CVEs) should kind of prove otherwise.

Comment: @jww `snprintf_s` would behave exactly the same as `snprintf` in this question

Comment: @pablo - you were ignoring the return value before you updated your answer.

Comment: @jww I was in the middle of the an edit when you've posted the comment. I don't write directly into the browser, I use an extension which allows me to write posts directly in vim, so when I write stuff, I don't see the updates of the site, only after I saved them. That's why I didn't realize right away that you made this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may use another sibling function, `asprintf(...)`, to allocate a proper piece of memory automatically:

```
char* timestr;
asprintf(&timestr, "%s:%s:%s", hr,min,sec);
```

The original solution doesn't work because `sizeof(char*)` == 8 (bytes) rather than 20, it's the pointer size itself and it doesn't depend on contents pointed by that or this pointer.